# Is there a way to initialize a GIT repository master branch with a README.md file using CLI extensions?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-devops-extensions

I am using the 'az repos create' command to create a git repo.
But at this point, there is no master branch created. I understand I can do a git add, commit and push to create the master branch. But this requires a clone to be made first. I am wondering if there is a way to automatically create the README.md using this CLI extension like while creating a repo from the GUI, it gives you an option to initialize the master branch with this file.

Comment: Hi @Rishabh, Is the explanation and suggestion in my answer helpful to you? If you have any questions about this ticket, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

I checked some commands for Azure Repos, such as '[**az repos create**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos?view=azure-cli-latest#az_repos_create)', '[**az repos update**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos?view=azure-cli-latest#az_repos_update)' and '[**az repos ref**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/ref?view=azure-cli-latest)', did not find any available option to initialize the new repository with a **`README.md`**.

I also checked the related REST API, also did not find any available option to do this.

Currently, after creating the new repository via the **`az repos create`** command, you need to open the repository page in your web browser (you can use the **`--open`** parameter in the command), then manually initialize the repository with a **`README.md`**.

[image]

If you really need the option, I recommend that you can report a feature request on the repository [**Azure/azure-cli**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/new/choose) to ask adding an option to allow initializing the repository with a **`README.md`** when creating it via the **`az repos create`** command.